# How can i determine the maximal length of a walk in a connected graph that goes through All the vertices

Tags: graph-theory

I know that a connected graph with n vertices has minimally n-1 edges but don't know how to use this information for a walk

Comment: Maybe you are interested in the minimal length of a path connecting all vertices? Path lengths can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: Yes, but a walk is what I'm trying to doggie or as in a path i believe vertices cannot be revisited.

Comment: @mepinon doggie?

Comment: Find not doggie, sorry

Answer (score 0):

In any connected graph you can have walks that go through all the vertices which are arbitrarily long. The easiest way to see this is to take any path that does so and then do the following to extend it: say $v_1, \dots v_n$ is your path, and that it goes through all your vertices. Then $v_1, \dots, v_n, v_{n-1}, v_n$ is a path of length $n+2$. Since you can go back and forth between the last two vertices in the walk an arbitrary number of times, there's no way you can bound the maximum length of a walk which goes through all the vertices.

Is this what you were really asking though? I somehow get the feeling there was a miscommunication.

Comment: I was given a specific scenario for a connected graph with 50 vertices and I had to prove that it could not have a length more than 96.  But I don't' want the answer, I want to understand the situation.  I know that in a connected graph could either be cyclic or it could be a tree.  If it is cyclic, there will be alternate routes to take when taking a walk and probably several different answers without finding a maximum. However, if it is a tree, then I know that in a tree the number of edges is one less than the number of vertices.  This would yield 49 edges.

Comment: In this walk, I don't want to repeat any edges unless I necessarily have to. I thought that perhaps having to go through each edge and back would give  a walk with a length of 98. However, if I don't start at the root and instead start at one of the leaves furthes from this root, then I could somehow get rid of one more edge yielding 97 edges. But I know that the answer is at most 96 edges.  I just don't know why. So I was looking for clarification or perhaps an algorithm that can always be used to determine the maximal length of a walk given any number of vertices.

Comment: I actually can one more of the values yielding 96 because I wouldn't have to go back through the initial leaf with which I started.  I don't know if there's an algorithm or if it just needs an explanation, which I'm guessing should suffice at least for the moment.